# How do I display a SwiftUI alert from outside of the ContentView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, alert

I am in the process of building a Swift app, and am trying to figure out how to display alerts. I have a separate swift file that is doing some calculations, and under a certain conditions I want it to display an alert to the user basically telling them something is wrong. However, most of the examples I have seen require the alert to be within the `ContentView` or otherwise somehow connected to a view, and I can't figure out how to display an alert from a separate file outside of any views.

Most of the examples I have seen look something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var showingAlert = false

var body: some View {
    Button("Show Alert") {
        showingAlert = true
    }
    .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
        Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
    }
}}
```

Comment: `.alert` is a View modifier.
From the docs: "...
 Because SwiftUI is a declarative framework, you don’t call a method at the moment you want to present the modal. Rather, you define how the presentation looks and the condition under which SwiftUI should present it. SwiftUI then detects when the condition changes and makes the presentation for you...". So from "outside" a View, just change the condition to present the alert.

Comment: The documentation says to always declare a `@State` as private, how would I access or set that from another class or file then?

Comment: Use ObservableObject view model instead of State and manage alert via property in view model from outside. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/64596846/12299030.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to show an `alert` on the UI when some condition happens in your calculations.
Where the calculations take place somewhere else in your code, eg a task monitoring a sensor.

Here I present an approach, using `NotificationCenter` as shown in the example code. Whenever and wherever you are in your code, send a `NotificationCenter.default.post...` as in the example code, and the alert will popup.

```
class SomeClass {
    static let showAlertMsg = Notification.Name("ALERT_MSG")
    
    init() {
        doCalculations() // simulate showing the alert in 2 secs
    }
    
    func doCalculations() {
        //.... do calculations
        // then send a message to show the alert in the Views "listening" for it
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SomeClass.showAlertMsg, object: nil)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let calc = SomeClass() // for testing, does not have to be in this View
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("calculating...")
            .alert("Important message", isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
            }
            // when receiving the msg from "outside"
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: SomeClass.showAlertMsg)) { msg in
                self.showingAlert = true // simply change the state of the View
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did almost exactly what I was looking for! However, this is in an AR app using RealityKit, and after the alert is displayed the camera feed from the app is heavily distorted, even after dismissing the alert. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: glad it answered at least part of your question. Sorry but I have no experience in AR app using RealityKit. I suggest you post your problem code and ask another question.