# Camera feed is getting heavily distorted after displaying alert within RealityKit Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, realitykit

I am making a RealityKit app, and just added an alert functionality following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71633749/how-do-i-display-a-swiftui-alert-from-outside-of-the-contentview). The alert is being triggered from a struct doing some calculations, specifically in the `else` clause of a `guard let` statement:

```
guard let example = ... else {     
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SomeClass.showAlertMsg, object: nil)
    }
}
```

The camera feed for the AR app shows up fine initially, but as soon as the alert is triggered from the above segment the feed gets heavily distorted. Even after dismissing the alert the feed remains distorted and essentially unusable. Is there a way to either prevent the distortion from occurring or to reset the camera feed/AR view after the alert is dismissed?

If it matters, the distortion seems to be a combination of the camera feed rotating 90 degrees and stretching vertically along the screen.

EDIT: Here is the `ContentView` where the alert is set up:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var showingError = false
    var body: some View {
        Zstack {
            //some unrelated things here
        }.alert("Error message", isPresented: $showingError) {
            Button("Dismiss", role: .cancel) {self.showingError = false}
        }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: someClass.showAlertMsg)) {msg in 
            self.showingError = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: show some code that reproduces your issue. At the very least show the camera feed/AR views and how it distorts after the alert is dismissed.

Comment: I actually have found the same issue in the last 48hours, and removing the asyncAfter "fixes" it. Out of interest is this on iOS14 or 15? On my 15 device the asyncAfter caused no issue.

Comment: I do also get this in the Xcode terminal 

`[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because allocation failed.`

Comment: I found the solution for my issue. The above CAMetalLayer log led me to take a look into my SwiftUI hierarchy again and I noticed I'd mixed some things up (had a group wrapping an Image and Text rather than the intended VStack, alongside a parent VStack that was supposed to be a Group). If you could share your SwiftUI body can take a look to see if anything obvious is in there causing the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminHall I just noticed that I am getting the exact same error you mentioned. This is iOS 15, getting rid of the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()` does not appear to change anything. I added the relevant pieces of my ContentView file to the original post, let me know if there is any other place that could be causing issues that I should look at or share. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hmm interesting. There could be something in your ZStack that is not as unrelated as you may think (yay SwiftUI...). I think there are two things I would try.

1. Move the alert to be attached to some other view (perhaps something in the ZStack)
2. Take a look at [_printChanges](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-find-which-data-change-is-causing-a-swiftui-view-to-update) to see if there is some peculiar updates happening in your view body.
3. Use something other than NotificationCenter publisher in the onReceive block to see if that is related to the cause